# Checking layout for compatibility with b/w printing in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, print-composer, layouts

I often have to produce paper maps that would likely later be printed in black and white, is there a way in ArcGIS Pro to apply a visual filter on a map to see how (approximately) the print layout will look like in B/W?

This is to make sure all the layers would not look like the same grey tone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows 10 you can go to the start menu, type color filters, then open the color filters dialog. Turn color filters off to turn your whole screen into gray scale.

There maybe a keyboard shortcut [as described here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-enable-grayscale-mode-windows-10) buy my employer seems to have disabled that feature.

Optionally you could send the finished map to a printer that allows you to print in back and white.

[image]

Comment: for whatever reason my remote desktop work PC does not have that option, fortunanetely my local machine does. Thanks, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

The [Color Oracle](https://colororacle.org/) software will do this for your entire screen, no matter what software you are using. It has options for three of the most common versions of colorblindness, in addition to grayscale. I've found it to be a really helpful piece of software, both for black and white printing checks, as well as choosing colorblind safe color combinations (beyond what ColorBrewer2 offers).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it won't work in my case. Using a corporate PC and getting anything installed there is next to impossible :(

Comment: I have the same problem at my current work too. @GBG's answer below does work on my corporate PC, so you might want to give that a shot if you're working on a Windows machine.